Proof of existence of the projection in a convex and complete part of a prehilbert space
I am given this theorem below:
If (E,<,>) is a Prehilbert space and C ⊂ E a convex and complete part of E then, $\forall x ∈ E$, there exists a unique element $p_C(x) ∈ C$ such that
$d(x; C) = ||x - p_C(x)||$
Moreover, $p_C(x)$ is the only element of C that verifies $<x - p_C(x), z - pC(x)>$ ≤ 0 for
all $z ∈ C$.
However, in the proof given to us, it is shown from scratch that a minimizing sequence in C is Cauchy. I don't understand why we need this step seeing that C is also stated to be complete. Also to do this, is the parallelogram law necessary?
This step of the proof is given below:
$d(x;C) = inf _{z \in C} ||x-z||$
We consider a minimising sequence $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb(N^*)}$ in C that verifies $d(x;C) \leq ||x-z_n|| < d(x;C)+\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \geq 1$
We show that this sequence is Cauchy. We use the parallelogram law:
$2||x-z_n||^2 + 2||x-z_m||^2 = ||(x-z_n) + (x -z_m)^2|| + ||(x-z_n) - (x-z_m) ||^2$
which gives
$2||x-z_n||^2 + 2||x-z_m||^2 = 4||x- \frac{z_n + z_m}{2}||^2 + ||z_n - z_m ||^2 $
Therefore we can write:
$||x-z_n||^2 = 2 ||x-z_n||^2 + 2||x-z_m||^2 - 4||x- \frac{z_n + z_m}{2}||^2$
By convexity $\frac{z_n + z_m}{2} \in C$ so $||x-\frac{z_n + z_m}{2} ||$
We obtain:
$||z_n - z_m||^2 \leq 2(d(x;C) +\frac{1}{n})^2 +2(d(x;C)+\frac{1}{m})^2 -4d(x;C)^2 $ which gives $lim_{n,m \to \infty} ||z_n - z_m|| = 0$
So $(z_n)$ is Cauchy

The proof finds a Cauchy sequence, and shows that its limit, assumed to exist by completeness, must be the distance-minimising point. Without completeness, there may be no such point. Without proving the sequence is Cauchy, we would have no reason to think completeness would help construct this point. The step is absolutely key to turning completeness into distance-minimising points. Why do you think it might be unnecessary?

I had the impression that as we are already in a complete space, any Cauchy sequence would have a point that is already in C so we would not have to prove it.
So the point of this part is rather to show that the limit (that is in C) is the distance minimizing point?

Ah, I see. The assumption that $E$ is pre-Hilbert specifically doesn't assume that $E$ is complete. A Hilbert space is complete, but a pre-Hilbert space, also known as an inner product space, may not be complete; it's just a real/complex vector space equipped with an inner product.

Okay I think I see it now, thank you very much!
